# Personalize a select form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I would like to personalize how a `select` input displays its selected value.

I have the following options for my `select` :

```
AAA - blabla
BBB - blabla
CCC - blabla
```

When I choose one, I want to display only the first three letters without whatever is after my dash. For example, selecting "AAA - blabla" would then only displays "AAA" in the select box.

Here a demonstration on jsfiddle on what I would want, displaying the behavior I want in an `input` field to clarify.

http://jsfiddle.net/LXkkB/1/

```
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="blue">blue - #0000FF</option>
    <option value="green">green - #00FF00</option>
    <option value="red">red - #FF0000</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor" onClick="checkColor()">
```

The current JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
var input = document.getElementById('txtColor');
select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = select.value;
}
```

EDIT1 :

I do have this:

```
function populateList() 
{
    var select = document.getElementById("cmbitems");
    var choice = select.selectedIndex;
    var textValue = select.options[choice].text;
    select.options[choice].text = textValue.substring(0,3);
}
```

But now, how I can refind my previous value when select all list

Comment: Please elaborate 'but exept to display the value in a input I want it diretly in my select form.' .

Comment: You display the `value` and not the string that you see in the selectbox, why don't you change the values to the preferred outcome in the input box? I may assume that they are unique?

Comment: my code is just to explain a little bit more my thought. the value in my real code is an ID. I don't want to display the value of the select but a shortcut of my string outcome

Comment: What does this mean `selecting "AAA - blabla" would then only displays "AAA" in the select box`? Which select box?

Comment: In the dropdown, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want first three letters of selected option's `text` not value.

Here is JS for that :

```
$('#cmbitems option:selected').text().substring(0,3);
```

where `.text()` will get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.
And `.substring()` method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

Here is **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/tfwyC/)** with Alert not as input text. I hope you will do that yourself.

Comment: Hi gagan, my issue is not in the substring but in the display of my new string in the select.

When you have selected you select instead of displaying the full text I'm want to display my new string.